Should questions about the Community of Christ (formerly known as RLDS) be tagged `lds` or something else?
In light of recent questions about Community of Christ (here, here, and here), should they use the lds tag or something else such as rlds or cofc ?
The Wikipedia article Comparison of the Community of Christ and the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints shows that since 1960 they have progressively diverging:

Significant doctrinal, organizational, and attitudinal changes in Community of Christ since 1960 have narrowed the similarities that remain between it and the LDS Church. While the doctrine and belief system of the LDS Church is highly centralized, systematic, and static, Community of Christ has adopted an adaptive, decentralized, and progressive approach to doctrine.


There's a community-of-christ tag already, not sure why the OP's didn't use it, but feel free to tag accordingly.
If the question compares LDS to CofC doctrine, then using lds as well is appropriate too.  (even though that moniker is fraught with confusion and controversy, I think we all agree it's less bad than mormon)

When it's a comparison of 2 denominations, wouldn't both tags need to be in the Q, at least for searchability?

@GratefulDisciple yeah, I meant "using [tag:lds] as well" is appropriate. Like [tag:python] [tag:python3.8]

I added rlds as a tag synonym for community-of-christ.

In my opinion not lds, the questions are only related to The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints in that the two share a common past. My knowledge of LDS stuff does no good to make me able to answer those questions, for example. And I believe that will be the same for most people answering lds questions here. The only thing I have a vague idea of is the legitimation question, but I wouldn't dare answer that either without more research.
But at least at the moment there don't seem to exist better tags, so probably new ones need to be created here. See other answer for better tags.
(And those questions could use a less confrontational tone, but that is just my taste.)
